# Using multiple sort descriptions with CollectionViewSource?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, sorting, collectionviewsource

I have a CollectionViewSource with sort descriptions defined however I want to change those sort descriptions based on a separate drop down the user can select. Ideally I'd like to implement all this with no codebehind.

```
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="SortedPeople" Source="{Binding People}">
<!--sort by first name then last name -->
            <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions> 
                <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="FirstName"/>
                <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="LastName"/>
            </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
<!-- another way to do this?
<!--sort by last name then first name -->
            <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions> 
                <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="LastName"/>
                <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="FirstName"/>
            </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>-->
        </CollectionViewSource>

(...xaml for drop down box which sets which set of sort descriptions to use...)
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I did it.

First create separate `CollectionViewSource` definitions

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="SortedFirstName" Source="{Binding People}">
        <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions> 
            <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="FirstName"/>
            <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="LastName"/>
        </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
    </CollectionViewSource>

    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="SortedLastName" Source="{Binding People}">
        <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions> 
            <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="LastName"/>
            <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="FirstName"/>
        </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
    </CollectionViewSource>
 </UserControl.Resources>
```

Then, let's say you have an ItemsControl and you want to style it to use different sorting methods. You can use DataTriggers:

```
<ItemsControl.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ItemsControl}">
        <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Source={StaticResource SortedLastName}}"/><!-- default value -->
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=SortBy}" Value="FirstName">
                <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Source={StaticResource SortedFirstName}}"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ItemsControl.Style>
```

Notice in the code above, that I bind to a property named `SortBy`. That is a property in my viewModel that is a string. When that property changes, I use the DataTrigger to change which CollectionViewSource I am using.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a combobox with multiple sort parameters.

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding SortByItemList}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSortByItem,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

In the view model, put this:

```
public string SelectedSortByItem
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedSortByItem;
        }

        set
        {
            _selectedSortByItem = value;
            OnSelectedSortByItemChanged(People, SelectedSortByItem);
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

public IList<People> OnSelectedSortByItemChanged(IList<People> items, string sortBy)
    {
        if (items == null || !items.Any())
        {
            return items;
        }

        var itemsToSort = items.ToList();

        if (sortBy == "FirstName")
        {
            return Sort(itemsToSort, "FirstName");
        }
        else if (sortBy == "LastName")
        {
            return Sort(itemsToSort, "LastName");
        }
        // put as many properties as you want here
  }

private static List<People> Sort(
            List<People> itemsToSort,
            string propertyPath,
            ListSortDirection sortDirection = ListSortDirection.Ascending)
{
   // put your sorting logic here.
}
```

Hope this helps.